# SUM with CASE and LEFT Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the code below, I'm trying to get the total `Net_Value` and  `Eaches` for the three years 2015-2017. However I cannot, for the life of me figure out what the syntax error is 
`[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '2015'.`

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2015' THEN Net_Value ELSE 0 END) AS 2015Sales,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2016' THEN Net_Value ELSE 0 END) AS 2016Sales,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2017' THEN Net_Value ELSE 0 END) AS 2017Sales,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2015' THEN Eaches ELSE 0 END) AS 2015Eaches,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2016' THEN Eaches ELSE 0 END) AS 2016Eaches,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(STR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),4) = '2017' THEN Eaches ELSE 0 END) AS 2017Eaches

  FROM DB;
```

The field itself is a numerical field, and am trying to use it as a string. Those values typically come through as `2015001` where the format is `yyyymmm`

Comment: This is because your column aliases start with a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are the column alias you're using - a valid SQL Server / T-SQL identifier **cannot** begin with a number.

If you really want to keep this, you **must** put these in square brackets like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4) = 2015 
              THEN Net_Value 
              ELSE 0 
        END) AS [2015Sales],
```

and you need to apply this to all your column aliases.

Comment: @GregdeLima: see [all the gory details about identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) in SQL Server / T-SQL

Comment: now get this...all the values are 0 !? Wonder if it's a field detail.

Comment: @GregdeLima: I believe the `LEFT(STR(..)` is probably *not* returning what you expect. I tried quickly: `SELECT '[' + STR(201611) + ']'` in my case returns `[    201611]` and `LEFT(STR(201611))` is empty .....

Comment: Interesting, yeah the field in our DB is for example `2015001` is Jan 2015 and stored as a numerical field, I believe.

Comment: Works with `STR()` Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are stored as dates, why aren't you using the `YEAR()` function.  I would also suggest putting the year at the end of the column alias.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date) = 2015 THEN Net_Value ELSE 0 END) AS Sales_2015
```

I think it is bad idea to use identifiers that need to be escaped -- they just make queries harder to write and to read.

And, if you just care about the results, why not use `GROUP BY`:

```
select year(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date), sum(net_value) as sales, sum(eaches) as eaches
from db
group by year(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date),
order by year(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date);
```

Comment: The OP was saying he's using a *numerical field* - e.g. stores `201611` as year/month in an `INT` column. But I agree - this is a horrible hack and should be fixed

Comment: Marc you're right, and it has to do with how we store our Fiscal Periods vs calendar dates. Don't disagree though!